# ¿PageCollectionView funciona diferente en WPF con el ListCollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Cuando paso el `ObservableCollection` y lo ordeno con Linq no funciona pero si lo paso  directamente funciona .En SilverLigth funcionaba pasando la lista ordenada. ¿A que se debe esto?

**Codigo en Silverlight**

```
ListaAOrdenar = new ObservableCollection<Units>();
Filtro = new PagedCollectionView(ListaAOrdenar.OrderBy(b => b.Unidad).ThenBy(c => c.fecha));
dataGrid.ItemsSource = Filtro;
```

**Codigo en WPF**

```
ListaAOrdenar = new ObservableCollection<Units>();
Filtro = new ListCollectionView(ListaAOrdenar.OrderBy(b => b.Unidad).ThenBy(c => c.fecha));
dataGrid.ItemsSource = Filtro;
```

Comment: Te lanza algun error? No especificaste que no funciona igual.

Comment: estas usando dos objetos diferentes.. y las grillas son iguales?

Comment: Asi es no funciona igual perdon por no aclarar eso, el silverlight muestra los datos correctamente y en wpf no muestra nada

Comment: @Einer no lanza ningun error solo no muestra los datos en wpf

Comment: @gbianchi pues uso lo mismo datagrid los que traen silverlight y wpf , es que hice una migracion hace poco de silverlight a wpf y el codigo es exactamente el mismo observableCollections para Units

Answer (score 0):

ItemSource espera un objeto Ienumerable,

```
     ListaAOrdenar.OrderBy(b => b.Unidad).ThenBy(c => c.fecha);
```

retorna IOrderedEnumerable

tendrás que pasarlo a Ienumerable

```
      ListaAOrdenar.OrderBy(b => b.Unidad).ThenBy(c => c.fecha).ToList()
```